# VBS file only works when double-clicked

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, vba

I am trying to use the Windows 8 Location API in order to get GPS coordinates from a built-in sensor, and return these coordinates to MS Access. However, due to the unsupported variant types used in the API, Access is unable to reliably use its objects.  I am trying to come up with a workaround using a VBScript file, and somehow returning the values to MS Access (using 2010 and 2013).  The easiest way I could think of was to spit out a txt file to be read by Access and then deleted.

My VBS File works perfectly when I run it from Windows Explorer (double-clicking the file) but I can't find a way to make it work properly when running it from VBA code.  Here is the VBS File:

```
Dim latlongfactory
Dim rptLong, rptLat
Dim report
Dim keepSleeping
Dim fs, f
Dim ts

Set latlongfactory = Wscript.CreateObject("LocationDisp.LatLongReportFactory", "llf_")
Set fs = Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

f = fs.BuildPath(CurrentDirectory, "gpsTempFile.txt")

keepSleeping = True
latlongfactory.ListenForReports(1000)

Sub llf_NewLatLongReport(report)    
    rptLong = report.Longitude
    rptLat = report.Latitude
    keepSleeping = False
End Sub

Do While keepSleeping
    Wscript.Sleep(20)
Loop

Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile(f, True)
ts.WriteLine rptLat & "," & rptLong
ts.Close

Set fs = Nothing
Set latlongfactory = Nothing
set report = Nothing
```

When run through VBA, it doesn't create the text file anymore, and I'm not entirely sure why.  I tried adding a Msgbox at the end of the script just to see if the code was running.  The Msgbox does come up.

The line I use to execute in Access VBA is:

```
Shell "Wscript """ & CurrentProject.Path & "\gpscoordinates.vbs""", 1
```

It runs the VBS file, but the text file isn't getting created and I cannot figure out why.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You're using a variable called `CurrentDirectory`. Where does its value get set?

Comment: I suspect that the file actually *is* created, but not in the place you expect, due to the uninitialized variable `CurrentDirectory`.

Comment: Well, I guess this is what happens when I research but don't read thoroughly.  For some reason I thought that CurrentDirectory was an available constant to refer to the file's current location.  This is where I tell myself always use Option Explicit...I qualified it now by creating a Wscript.Shell.  Now I see that when double-clicking the file, the active directory is where the file is, but when I run from VBA it's the My Documents folder (I found the file there).  So now my question is how do I specify the directory location of the VBS file itself?

Comment: f = fs.BuildPath(fs.GetparentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName), "gpsTempFile.txt")

I figured it out myself.  Thanks everyone!  How do I properly close out this question?

Comment: Thank you for all your help!  I'll mark yours since you led me in the right direction haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the output file to be created in the same folder in which the script resides, you can use the [`ScriptFullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc5ywscw%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property of the `WScript` object:

```
outputFolder = fs.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
f = fs.BuildPath(outputFolder, "gpsTempFile.txt")
```